# How do I get multiple scripts prompted with an alias in Cygwin?

Tags: linux, bash, python, cygwin, bash-scripting

**I want to run one command, then bring up a second, but modify it first before pressing enter on it.** (Cygwin)

I usually just type it all out like this:

```
svn up 8.0; ./merge.py 8.0 12345
```

I also have to do this with different versions and revisions, so after that, I type out all this again for each one:

```
svn up 8.1; ./merge.py 8.1 12345
```

The problem is, 12345 always changes, so I have to just up arrow and delete and re type it.

So what I want to do is type this:

```
m8 12345
```

or

```
m81 12345
```

or

```
m8 54321
```

For each different one. The results would be:

```
$ m8 12345
$ svn up 8.0; ./merge.py 8.0 12345
```

(but not actually run, just typed in for me in the prompt)

```
$ m81 12345
$ svn up 8.1; ./merge.py 8.1 12345
```

(but not actually run, just typed in for me in the prompt)

```
$ m8 54321
$ svn up 8.0; ./merge.py 8.0 54321
```

(but not actually run, just typed in for me in the prompt)

At that point I could press enter, or change the 12345 around, or do nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an `alias` to the first part of the command. When you're done, you can `unalias` it.

What you would do in your example is:

```
alias m8='svn up 8.0; ./merge.py 8.0'
```

Which then lets you do:

```
m8 12345
```

When you're done, you can delete the alias:

```
unalias m8
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `bash`'s history capabilities. Put the following in your `.bashrc` file:

```
shopt -s histverify
```

Now, at the command-line, you can type <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>r</kbd>, the start typing `svn up`. It should search back through your history for the first command that begins "svn up". Repeated presses of <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> will find previous such commands. If at any time you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the `histverify` option we set above will cause the currently displayed command to be displayed on the command-line for editing, not executed immediately.

This isn't exactly what you asked for, but may work just as well. It's possible to write a function that might behave similarly (`$ m 8.1 54321`), but the details are tricky.

Answer (score 0):

Write a shell script or function (e.g., called `m`) that does something like this:

> *Validate arguments:* `$1` *and* `$2` *are numeric.*
>    *Compute* `ver_num` *from* `$1`*; e.g.,* `8` –> `8.0`*,* `81` –> `8.1`
>   `my_command="svn up $ver_num; ./merge.py $ver_num $2"`
>   `echo "$my_command"`
>   `history -s "$my_command"`

You’ll have to run it as `m 8 12345` (instead of `m8 12345`).  The `history -s` command will put "$my_command" into the history list without executing it, so you should be able to press <kbd>Cursor Up</kbd>, optionally edit the command, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> –– or do nothing.